# Perl: Regex - Unrecognized escape \s passed through

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $find = "(.*\s+)(subject:)(.*)(_1)(\s+.*)";
my $replace = '"\nsubject: \t\t$3_2"';

my $var_1 = "Time: 1000-1200    subject:    Physic_1    Class: Room A";
my $var_2 = "Time: 1000-1200    subject:    Math_1  Class: Room A";
$var_1 =~ s/$find/$replace/ee;
$var_2 =~ s/$find/$replace/ee;
print $var_1."\n";
print $var_2."\n";
```

I expect the output only extract the subject and change _1 to _2 like:

```
Output:
subject:      Physic_2
subject:      Math_2
```

However, what I get is:

```
Output:
Unrecognized escape \s passed through at test.pl line 20.
Unrecognized escape \s passed through at test.pl line 20.
Time: 1000-1200 subject:        Physic_1        Class: Room A
Time: 1000-1200 subject:        Math_1  Class: Room A
```

How can I escape those \t, \s+, \n as on string variable as perl regex pattern?

UPDATE: 
If I do something like this:

```
my $pattern = 's/(.*\s+)(subject:)(.*)(_1)(\s+.*)/\nsubject: \t\t$3_2/g';
my $var = "Time: 1000-1200   subject:    Physic_1    Class: Room A";
$var =~ $pattern;
print $var."\n";
```

It give the output, seem like nothing change:

```
Time: 1000-1200   subject:    Physic_1    Class: Room A
```

Answer (score 4):

Double quotes interpolate backslashed characters. `\s` has a special meaning in a regex, but not in doublequotes - hence the warning. Use single quotes instead.

```
my $find = '(.*\s+)(subject:)(.*)(_1)(\s+.*)';
```

or, if you need double quotes for some other reasons, double the backslashes that should survive in the regex:

```
my $find = "(.*\\s+)(subject:)(.*)(_1)(\\s+.*)";
```

Comment: If I do something else, like my updated post, seem like couldn't work

Comment: To ask a new question, create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the first line exactly as you did it in the second line:

```
my $find = '(.*\s+)(subject:)(.*)(_1)(\s+.*)';
```

Output:

```
subject:                    Physic_2

subject:                    Math_2
```